# Default gateway ping too high

Tags: networking, router, ping, modem, gateway

I have a cable modem router C7000-100NAS.

I can't seem to figure out why when I ping the default gateway(192.168.0.1) I get high pings ranging from 8ms to 500 ms, this is NEVER below 2ms as it should be.

I've even tried to connect using wired connection but still couldn't get something like as low as <4. I've tried disconnecting everything else, restarting/resetting the router.

Does it have anything to do with the cable/router being two in one? This greatly effects my gaming ping as well as streaming to my Nvidia Shield.

Here is the result of ping:

[image: Pings]

What I don't get is why during tracert I get smaller numbers:

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't have to do with a hybrid device, or even wireless/wired - you should never get such high latency from your gateway. The specific pattern you see where it spikes up at times is called jitter and it is usually caused by a resource issue. It could be bandwidth - something else in the house is utilizing a lot of bandwidth from the router, or could just simply be load. Even routers have limits when it comes to CPU/RAM, so if it is too busy routing, it may take a while to respond to ICMP packets, or even just too busy to handle data packets in a reasonable amount of time sometimes.

Comment: I have a total of 21 devices connected, if this $200+ router can't handle that many devices then what can? Also I would like to add restarting the router does help but it eventually goes back to misbehaving.

Comment: Just because a device is $200+ doesn't mean it can handle that many devices and all the traffic they push through it. Most SOHO routers don't have all that great backplanes for handling a ton of traffic and it is most likely just a single gigabit port that links the switch to the router internally. So your 21 devices all connected at 100mb+ must all compete for space in that 1000mb pipe and rely on shared CPU/RAM resources to handle all the processing/routing/translation for all the packets in/out of that device.

Comment: https://kb.netgear.com/24043/How-many-clients-can-you-connect-wirelessly-to-a-NETGEAR-router - "since the router's wireless channel is shared between all the wireless clients, adding clients will inevitably result in slower network access for all clients. This will be particularly noticeable if some of the clients are using a lot of wireless bandwidth" - so while you CAN connect much more than 21 devices, it doesn't mean that the router can handle them all doing stuff at the same time.

Comment: 6 of them are Google Homes, 2 thermostats, 1 printer, 2 bulbs, 1 smart plug, 3 android tv(I can only watch 1 at a time), 1 raspberry pi I wonder where all this bandwidth is going that you talk about.

Comment: Also I've noticed the router randomly assigns some devices IP starting with 67. or 98.. etc while it should only do 192.168.0.xx. Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @MuhammadAli You definitely should not have those IPs in your subnet, unless you've manually configured it that way. This is an old thread so hopefully this has resolved by getting a new router, ISP, network etc. Let us know.

Comment: @TonyH Yes I resolved this by buying another ~$40 router from tp link and sharing most of the load on this new router. Lesson learned: Do not buy these expensive routers that list that they can handle tons of devices and you don't need anything else.

Comment: @MuhammadAli Expensive routers have their place and uses, but I usually make sure they fully support something like OpenWRT/LEDE to make sure they are running at their best (hopefully), or at least you can deeply inspect what happening at a system level.

Comment: It’s important to understand that ping and traceroute are not the same. Ping uses _ICMP Echo Reply_ packets. Traceroute relies on _ICMP Time Exceeded_ packets by deliberately sending packets with a low TTL (Time To Live) values. Usually the latter is much less reliable, but who’s to say it can’t be the other way around. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinging from another device, such as an android Phone, or another Windows PC?

The other thing is to try a different cable.

What you want to do is eliminate all possible variables to check if your router is the problem. They are currently your PC and your cable. If you get the same results with both of these things changed then you can start looking at your router.

If you are still having trouble. Consider resetting your router and reconfiguring it.

Best of luck

Comment: I've already tried different device, I get the same result. By cable do you mean the ethernet? because I've tried both ethernet cable and WiFi.